# sharepoint site colonne type to upload external image

Tags: sharepoint-2013, content-type

i wanna create a custom site column for image , i tried this type : 
Image with formatting and constraints for publishing , i t doesn't give me the ability to upload image from my desktop only from SharePoint

Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create columns that can upload files. You should use a document library and/or inherit your custom content type from the default document content type.

That way, you can upload whatever documents.